# Two Way Anova with multiple factor experiment

Tags: sas

I'm trying to use SAS to construct an ANOVA table for a multiple factor experiment. The question I'm trying to solve says that the MSE (error mean square) is 6.598 with 36 degrees of freedom. I have tried it with the code below, but am getting the incorrect value for MSE. Given that there are 36 treatment combinations, and r = 2 observations were taken on each, can you please check where I'm going wrong? Code:

```
DATA W;
    INPUT E A D F Y;
    LINES;
/*put data*/
;

proc glm data=wthr;
    classes e a f;
    model y=e a f ea ef af eaf;
    Means e a f;
    MEANS e / scheffe CLDIFF ALPHA=0.10;
    estimate 'cont_vs_alt' e 1 -1/divisor=2;

proc sort data=wthr;
    by e a f;

proc means noprint mean ;
    var y;
    by e a f;
    output out=percmean mean=av_y;

proc print;
    var e a f av_y;

proc sort;
    by e a f;

proc plot;
    by e;
    plot av_ya=f/vpos=19 hpos=60;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: DATA W;
 INPUT E A D F Y;
 LINES;
/*put data*/
;
proc glm data=wthr; 
classes e a f; 
model y=e a f e*a e*f a*f e*a*f; 
Means e a f; 
MEANS e / scheffe CLDIFF ALPHA=0.10; 
estimate 'cont_vs_alt' e 1 -1/divisor=2; proc sort data=wthr; 
by e a f; 
proc means noprint mean ; 
var y; 
by e a f; 
output out=percmean mean=av_y; 
proc print; 
var e a f av_y; proc sort; 
by e a f; 
proc plot; by e; 
plot av_y*a=f/vpos=19 hpos=60; 
run; quit;

Comment: You can edit your question and so I'd suggest you put that code in the question, not as a comment.

Comment: Matt, It gives an error when I do that!